# Swift array to array of tuples

Tags: swift, tuples

I have the following two arrays:

```
let xaxis = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
let yaxis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would like to merge them into an array that looks like this:

```
[ ("monday", 1), ("tuesday", 2), ("wednesday", 3), ("thursday", 4), ("friday", 5)]
```

Comment: This is not a dictionary that you are showing , its an array of tuples

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `zip` and `map`:

```swift
let xaxis = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
let yaxis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let tuples = Array(zip(xaxis, yaxis))  // or `zip(xaxis, yaxis).map { ($0, $1) }`
```

---

I know you asked about a tuple, but you can also consider a custom object, e.g.:

```swift
struct Day {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}

let names = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let days = zip(names, values).map(Day.init)
```

Comment: These methods are faster as compared to simple for loops or not, please give your suggestion

Comment: The above is my suggestion. Avoid premature optimization. Always use the most concise, most expressive syntax, and don't worry about optimization unless it can possibly have material impact. The performance difference is indistinguishable with 5 items. And it's practically nonexistent when doing release builds. All of that having been said, I wonder why you're using tuples at all. Or why are you using an array of string literals as opposed to `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols`. There are many things I'd worry about before spending a second thinking about replacing `zip`/`map` with `for` loops.

Comment: I used those two arrays as an example but the real app won't have months or any calendar data in the array. I just wanted an example of how to convert two arrays, one of type string and one of type int, into an array of tuples.

Comment: `.map { ($0, $1) }` doesn't transform, so `Array(zip(xaxis, yaxis))` is better, de-conflating the `transform`+`Array.init` that map normally entails.

Comment: Agreed. `Array(zip(…))` is probably better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let arrayMerged = zip(xaxis, yaxis).map { ($0, $1) }
```

or this:

```
let arrayMerged = Array(zip(xaxis, yaxis))
```

Comment: The latter answer is  I wounder which is faster?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let xaxis = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]

let yaxis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var newArr = [(String, Int)]()

for i in 0..<xaxis.count {
        newArr.append((xaxis[i], yaxis[i]))
}
print(newArr)
```

Comment: This makes no use of the `yaxis` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
let tuples = xaxis.enumerated().map { (index, value) in (value, yaxis[index]) }
```

Assuming `yaxis`'s count always matches to `xaxis`.

Comment: This also assumes the values in the `xaxis` array are unique.

Comment: the code looks short and clean but has time complexity, if used on a large array.  answer from 3stud1ant3 is recommended if considered time complexity