# Swift convert an array to array of tuples

Tags: swift

I have an array like this:

```
[Shivam, Shiv, Shantanu, Mayank, Neeraj]
```

I want to create an array of `tuples(key , value)` from this array only with `key` being `first character` and `value` being an `array of strings`:

Like this:

```
[

(**key**: S , **value**: [Shivam, Shiv, Shantanu]),

 (**key**: M , **value**: [Mayank]), 

 (**key**: N , **value**: [Neeraj])

]
```

PS: It is not a duplicate to this post [Swift array to array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911256/swift-array-to-array-of-tuples). There OP wants to merge two arrays to create an array of tuples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Step 1: Create a grouped dictionary

  ```
  let array = ["Shivam", "Shiv", "Shantanu", "Mayank", "Neeraj"]
  let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {String($0.prefix(1))})
  ```
- Step 2: Actually there is no step 2 because you are discouraged from using tuples for persistent data storage, but if you really want a tuple array

  ```
  let tupleArray = dictionary.map { ($0.0, $0.1) }
  ```

A better data model than a tuple is a custom struct for example

```
struct Section {
    let prefix : String
    let items : [String]
}
```

then map the dictionary to the struct and sort the array by `prefix`

```
let sections = dictionary.map { Section(prefix: $0.0, items: $0.1) }.sorted{$0.prefix < $1.prefix}
print(sections)
```

Comment: Actually I first used Dictionary only, but later on i had to sort the dictionary based on the key that is characters but couldn't do it. Tried everything to sort dictionary but couldn't so i moved on to array of tuples. I will try your answer and let you know.

Comment: I updated the answer providing a more suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: `let sections = dictionary.map(Section.init)`